# Can't get value of checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Here's the HTML:

```
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox-detailed male_input">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
                    <label for="male">
                    <span class="checkbox-detailed-tbl">
                        <span class="checkbox-detailed-cell">
                            <span class="checkbox-detailed-title">Male</span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-detailed female_input" style="margin-left: 25px!important">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                    <label for="female">
                    <span class="checkbox-detailed-tbl">
                        <span class="checkbox-detailed-cell">
                            <span class="checkbox-detailed-title">Female</span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded" id="user_submit">Sign In</button>
        </form>
```

And Here's the javascript section:

```
var user_gender = $("input[name='gender']:checked");
var user_submit = $('#user_submit');

user_submit.click(function(){
    console.log(user_gender.val())
});
```

I also tried `var user_gender = $("input[name=gender]:checked");` (without quotes between gender) and `var user_gender = $("input:radio[name='gender']:checked");`, it still didn't work. It's logging undefined for user_gender variable, am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the checked radio *when the page loads*. You instead need to get it *when the button is clicked*.

To do that move the selector inside the event handler:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission. Remove once you've finished testing
  var $user_gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked');
  console.log($user_gender.val())
});
```

A couple of things to note here. Firstly, the naming convention for variables which contain jQuery objects is to prefix their names with a `$` as I've done in the above example.

Secondly, when dealing with forms, hook to the `submit` event of the `form` itself, not the `click` event of the `submit` button. This is for accessibility reasons. It's also better semantically.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I'm using socket.io. Can't use regular forms(GET/POST).

Comment: That's fine - it's unrelated to what I suggested in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You want to move the query within the function like this:

```
var user_submit = $('#user_submit');

user_submit.click(function(){
    var user_gender = $("input[name='gender']:checked");
    console.log(user_gender.val())
});
```

What you are doing is getting the checked values before you are submitting, which is probably nothing at the time of loading the page.